# Can we find $\lambda$ with $B(\lambda, |\lambda|) \subseteq K?$

Tags: general-topology, analytic-geometry, separation-axioms

Let $K$ be a compact subset of the positive real axis, viewed as a subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $a$ be an element not on the positive real axis, i.e. $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus [0, \infty[$.

In a proof I'm reading, it is claimed that there is $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with

$$K\subseteq B_\mathbb{C}(\lambda, |\lambda|), \quad a \notin B_\mathbb{C}(\lambda, |\lambda|)$$

This is intuitively clear but I can't formally prove it.

This may have something to do with separations axioms or Lebesgue coverings.

Comment: This not true in general. Does $K$ need to be connected? Otherwise take $K=[1,2] \cup [4,5]$ and $a=3$.

Comment: @abcdef Sorry, I forgot to mention that $a$ cannot be a positive real number.

Comment: Does that mean $a$ is a negative real number? Because if $a$ is allowed to be complex it still is false in general.

Comment: Did you try using polar coordinates? You are just looking for a circle $C$ with radius $\lvert \lambda \rvert$, passing through $0$. Call $A$ the chord with endpoints at the two intersections of $C$ with $\Bbb{R}$, $0, x_A$. Since $a \notin \Bbb{R}$, all you need is to find a radius wide enough so that $K \subseteq A$ and that the shorter arc of $C$ between $0$ and $x_A$ has "height" less than $\operatorname{Im}(a)$.

Comment: No $a$ can be complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_K = \sup K$ and without loss of generality assume that $a$ lies in the first quadrant. Note that the boundary $C$ of the ball $B_{\Bbb{C}}(\lambda, \lvert \lambda \rvert)$ is just a circle with radius $\lvert \lambda \rvert$, passing through $0$. Therefore, we're looking for a circle like in the picture below, where $c = \lambda$, and where $x_C$ is the other intersection of $C$ with $\Bbb{R}$.

[image: Construction of the circle]

Clearly (by construction) the distances between $c$ and $O$, $c$ and $x_C$, and $c$ and the highest point of $C$ are all $\lvert \lambda \rvert$. Therefore such a circle exists if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
x_C = 2\cos(\alpha) \lvert \lambda \rvert \geq x_K \\
\lvert \lambda \rvert < \sin(\alpha) \lvert \lambda \rvert + \operatorname{Im}(a)
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha = \lvert \arg(\lambda) \rvert$ is the angle between the real axis and the segment joining $\lambda$ and $0$. In particular, these equations have a solution if and only if
$$
\frac{x_K}{\operatorname{Im}(a)} < 2 \frac{\cos(\alpha)}{1 - \sin(\alpha)}
$$
which is always possible since $\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{1 - \sin(\alpha)} \to \infty$ as $\alpha \to \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that $a\leq 0$, let $s= \sup K <\infty$ and $t = \inf K$.
Because $K \subset \mathbb{R}^+, t > 0$ and we have that $K \subset B(s,s-t/2)$ and $a \notin B(s,s-t/2)$ because $ B(s,s-t/2) \subset (t/2, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: From the question, I'd say that $a \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \Bbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Yes, exactly @A.P.